# Enviar Array Javascript al controlador MVC vb

Tags: javascript, mvc

```
var list = new Array();                

for (var x = 0; x < tab1; x++) {
    var lsGrupo = "grupo3_" + x;
    var objGrupo = document.getElementsByName(lsGrupo);
    for (var i = 0; i < objGrupo.length; i++) {
        if (objGrupo[i].checked) {
            if (i == 0) {
                list.push("Bueno");
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                list.push("Malo");
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                list.push("No Aplica");
            }
        }
    }                             
} // fin

// Metodo guardar
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("Guardar_CabeceraJSON", "Creciendo")', { "fuente": fuente, "eps": eps, "servicio": servicio, "resp1": resp1, "resp2": resp2, "sugerencia": sugerencia, "myJson": JSON.stringify(list) }, function (resultado) {
    $.each(JSON.parse(resultado), function (index, Data) {
        if (Data.Result == 'True') {
            alert("Datos guardados correctamente.")
            // NotificacionPopup('success', 'Datos guardados 

            correctamente');                                   
            location.reload(true);
        } else { alert('Error al intentar guardar el 

            registro.'); }
    });
});
}
```

no sé si lo estoy enviando bien o que pero no sé cómo recibirlo del lado del controlador.

Comment: Aqui ahi una buena respuesta espero que te ayude. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form

Comment: Que controlador estas usando?

Comment: Tocayo, tendrás que mostrarnos que controlador utilizar

Comment: ya lo hice amigo, de todos modos gracias.:D